# multivalued field in solr returns one item only

Tags: mysql, solr, multivalue

I am newbie in solr,
i have a table like this

```
id         infield        body
---------------------------------------------
1           ValX          Article1-Body
1           ValY          Article1-Body
1           ValZ          Article1-Body
2           ValW          Article2-Body
....
```

and my mysql query looks like

```
select A.id,B.infield, A.body from A inner join B on A.id=B.id;
```

and in schema.xml i have this

```
<field indexed="true" multiValued="true" name="infield" stored="true" type="string"/>
```

now when my query is * : *, i am supposed to get all infield like below

```
<str name="id">1</str>
<str name="body">Article1-Body</str>
<arr name="infield">    
   <str>ValX</str>
   <str>ValY</str>
   <str>ValZ</str>
</arr>
```

**but i am getting this**

```
<str name="id">1</str>
<str name="body">Article1-Body</str>
<arr name="infield">    
   <str>ValX</str>
</arr>
```

**EDIT**
my dataconfig.xml contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource autoCommit="true" batchSize="-1" convertType="true" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" password="pass" url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/test" user="root"/>
  <document name="items">
    <entity name="root" pk="id" preImportDeleteQuery="data_source:10" query="select A.id,B.infield, A.body from A inner join B on A.id=B.id;" transformer="TemplateTransformer">
      <field column="data_source" template="10"/>
      <field column="data_source_type" template="Jdbc"/>
      <field column="data_source_name" template="Test"/>
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

any idea what might be wrong?
Thanks

Comment: What does the document posted to solr (for indexing) look like?

Comment: Not sure if i got your question correctly,, but i am indexing mysql tables for articles and here infield represents the category of the article itself

Comment: @dwhelan : I have edited the question as well... i hope it is clearer now

Comment: Can you show us your data-config.xml? Do you have nested entities or just one?

Comment: @javanna : Question has been edited... please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query probably produces multiple records with the same id and hence the separate/individual records are getting overridden as they have the same id.
So you end up with just one infield value.
For multivalued fields you should include it as a [sub entity which returns multiple values](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#What_is_a_row.3F).

Comment: you are right,,, more than one record are returned with the same id, but could you plz clarify more.. do u mean that i have to have nested query? i have added my dataconfig.xml to the question... what shall i change in it? thanks

Comment: Check the feature entity example @ http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Full_Import_Example